# How can I populate this complex List?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have a complex List data structure which i want to populate but i just cant seem to find a way to seed values to it.

```
List<Dictionary<List<int>, int>> l1 = new List<Dictionary<List<int>, int>>();
```

I want something like this,

```
l1.add( (1,2,3), 6);
```

I want to add a list of numbers and its sum.

Comment: Using a List as the key type of a dictionary seldomly makes sense because two lists with the exact same content will not be recognized to be the same. Please tell a bit more about what your actual task is for a good answer.

Comment: @NineBerry even though one could create the dictionary with a custom comparer...

Comment: Basically @NineBerry my task is to find the Sum of the largest increasing subsequence in an array and also print that subsequence.

Comment: @user7334855 I don't really understand how this datastructure is going to help with this task. To solve the task you basically only need to traverse the array once and use a handful of integer variables to store some array indexes and sums on the way.

Comment: I have found a way to do this all and that too in an extremely simple way. Shall i share the code here in the comments? @NineBerry

Comment: @user7334855 Not in the comments, but you can add an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really not sure why you're doing that but if you really have to

```
var list = new List<Dictionary<List<int>, int>>();
list.Add(new Dictionary<List<int>, int> {{ new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, 6}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you *really* need a list of dictionary of list. Still, you can write some kind of extension method:

```
public static ListHelpers
{
    public void AddSum(this List<Dictionary<List<int>, int>> list, params int[] values)
    {
        list.Add(new Dictionary<List<int>, int> { values.ToList(), values.Sum() });
    }
}
```

Then use it with:

```
l1.AddSum(1, 2, 3);
```